# Chrome showing ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR for Youtube GET https://somerandomhost.googlevideo.com/generate_204

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, http-proxy, proxy-server

When using an HTTP Forward-Proxy (like TinyProxy but also happens with others) if I load a few YouTube tabs in Chrome I always get a few errors `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` when calling `GET https://some-random-host.googlevideo.com/generate_204`.
(e.g. `GET https://rr2---sn-p5qs7nzk.googlevideo.com/generate_204 net`).

If I don't use any proxy I don't get those errors.
If I use Microsoft Firewall (either with IP routes or using explicit L7 HTTPS Proxy) I also don't see those errors.

What exactly are those errors?
Are they because YouTube client only works with HTTPS (SSL-terminating) proxy?

UPDATE: I've just used MITM proxy to understand better, and it looks like the server (YT) is sometimes just disconnecting that request (no answer). So I assume the ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR is just a the way Chrome tells us that an HTTPS-proxied connection couldn't get a response?

Comment: Which SSL/TLS certificate are you being served while in the proxy configuration?

Comment: @Ramhound for both TinyProxy (no SSL) and for Azure Firewall I get the same Google certificate (*.google.com) that I get if I don't use any proxy. And I'm wondering how Azure can do that. And wondering if that Chrome error is just caused by regular dropped connections.

Comment: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR is a client time and or cache issue.